# Net Plugin vs BNet Plugin

Tags: nodeos, net-plugin

I'm using NodeOS 1.3.2 and I'm trying to understand what the difference between the BNet Plugin and the Net Plugin are. As I understand it, BNet is meant to be a new, fancy replacement for Net that can run alongside it for backwards compatibility purposes. If these assumptions are incorrect, please let me know.

I have a couple questions:

1) Does NodeOS require the Net plugin to run? If not, how do I turn it off? I haven't listed it in the plugins section and I've commented out all of the configuration options for it, yet it still seems to be running (which causes me issues downstream)

2) Is there a net_api_plugin equivalent for BNet? If not, why?

Thanks